# PrintWriter writes something strange to txt

Tags: java, printwriter, chars

I wanted this program to write UTF-8 letters in .txt file but as a result i have numbers and other non-sense chars. Could anyone help me to solve it? I have no idea how to make it in print writer. I'll appreciate any help. Here's my code.

```
//all imports

public class Main extends Application {

    Stage okno;
    TableView<Produkt> tabela;
    TextField nazwaWejscie, iloscWejscie;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        okno = primaryStage;
        okno.setTitle("Stwórz listę zakupów");

        // Kolumna nazwa
        TableColumn<Produkt, String> kolumnaNazwa = new TableColumn<>("Nazwa");
        kolumnaNazwa.setMinWidth(200);
        kolumnaNazwa.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nazwa"));

        // Kolumna ilosc
        TableColumn<Produkt, Double> kolumnaIlosc = new TableColumn<>("Ilość");
        kolumnaIlosc.setMinWidth(100);
        kolumnaIlosc.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ilosc"));

        // Wprowadź nazwę
        nazwaWejscie = new TextField();
        nazwaWejscie.setPromptText("Nazwa (string)");
        nazwaWejscie.setMinWidth(100);

        // Wprowadź ilość
        iloscWejscie = new TextField();
        iloscWejscie.setPromptText("Ilość (double)");

        // Przyciski
        Button dodaj = new Button("Dodaj");
        dodaj.setOnAction(e -> kliknijDodaj());
        Button usun = new Button("Usuń");
        usun.setOnAction(e -> kliknijUsun());

        Button stworzListe = new Button("Zapisz listę");
        stworzListe.setOnAction(e -> zapiszListe());

        HBox pojemnik = new HBox();
        pojemnik.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        pojemnik.setSpacing(10);
        // wstaw pola i przyciski w jeden rząd
        pojemnik.getChildren().addAll(nazwaWejscie, iloscWejscie, dodaj, usun, stworzListe);

        tabela = new TableView<>();
        tabela.setItems(getProdukt());
        tabela.getColumns().addAll(kolumnaNazwa, kolumnaIlosc);

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(tabela, pojemnik);

        Scene scena = new Scene(vBox);
        okno.setScene(scena);
        okno.show();
    }

    // Funkcja dodania produktu
    public void kliknijDodaj() {
        Produkt Produkt = new Produkt();
        Produkt.setNazwa(nazwaWejscie.getText());
        Produkt.setIlosc(Double.parseDouble(iloscWejscie.getText()));
        tabela.getItems().add(Produkt);
        nazwaWejscie.clear();
        iloscWejscie.clear();
    }

    // Funkcja usunięcia produktu
    public void kliknijUsun() {
        ObservableList<Produkt> ProduktWybrany, wszystkieProdukty;
        wszystkieProdukty = tabela.getItems();
        ProduktWybrany = tabela.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

        ProduktWybrany.forEach(wszystkieProdukty::remove);
    }

    public ObservableList<Produkt> getProdukt() {
        ObservableList<Produkt> produkty = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        return produkty;
    }

    // Funkcja dodania listy do pliku
    public void zapiszListe() {

        ArrayList<Produkt> produkty = new ArrayList<Produkt>(tabela.getItems());
        int licznik = 1;
        try {
            File plik = new File("C:\\Users\\Sebastian\\Desktop\\lista.txt");
            if (!plik.exists()) {
                plik.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(plik, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            for (int i = 0; i < produkty.size(); i++) {
                pw.println(licznik + ". " + produkty.get(i));
                licznik++;
            }
            pw.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Błąd: ");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You must share code or example code you using for more understanding your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `FileWriter` uses the `default encoding` as mentioned in the `javadoc` I quote:

> The constructors of this class assume that the default character
>   encoding and the default byte-buffer size are acceptable.

You need to define explicitly the `encoding` as next for example:

```
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(plik, true), "UTF-8");
```

The second problem in your code is related to the fact that you print `licznik + ". " + produkty.get(i)` which does a `String` concatenation of an integer, ". " and an object of type `Produkt` for which you obviously did not override the method `toString()` which means that it calls the default implementation defined in `Object` that only returns the name of the class followed by @ and the hash code of the object in hexadecimal. In other words, to fix your problem simply implement your own `toString` method in `Produkt`

Comment: thanks, I'd like you to explain it a bit to me. Should I use this Writer class as well in my whole code?

Comment: replace your FileWriter with this writer in your code, FileWriter is not an option in your case

Comment: It helped, thanks alot. I just added to class Produkt `public String toString() { 
        return this.nazwa + ", " + this.ilosc;
    } `